# List Iterate in paragraph form in JSF page

Tags: java, jsf

I want to iterate list in paragraph form in JSF page...

for E.g.

I have list and i want to iterate it's value as

like

```
list<String>={'test1','test2','test3'}
```

I want JSF output as

```
test1:..test2:...test3...
```

how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

Hope this is helpful.

```
<html xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"> 

<ui:repeat var="test" value="#{someClass.methodThatReturnList}">
   #{test}:
</ui:repeat>
```

Answer (score 1):

JSF way is `h:dataTable` but since you want it just to be displayed in one line you can go with JSTL

```
<c:forEach items="${yourBean.youeLIst}" var="para">
        <c:out value="${para}"/>
</c:forEach>
```